# Catch a Hibernate exception upon SpringBoot application startup?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm trying to use Spring Boot 1.2.6 with `HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration`.  It works great; that is it "magically" creates by entityManager, and does all the configuration for me out of the box using my spring.jpa.* properties.

However, in the case of a DB error (invalid credentials, DB not accessible, etc), I cannot find a clean way to catch a Hibernate exception upon startup.

I supposed I can catch all BeanCreationException and check the root cause, but that seems like quite a hack:

```
    ConfigurableApplicationContext context;
    try {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
        context = app.run(args);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // check if it is a DB error.  
        if( ExceptionUtils.getRootCause(e) instanceof( HibernateException ) ){
            System.out.println( "You are having trouble with the DB: " + ExceptionUtils.getRootCauseMessage(e) );
        }
    }
    finally{
        // finished so close the context
        if( context != null )
            context.close();
    }
```

Is there a cleaner / neater way of doing this without losing the ability to use the auto configuration?  Additionally, short of parsing the error message, is there a way to determine what the Hibernate/DB error is (ie: invalid creds, DB not validated, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of catching a very generic `HibernateException`, you can try catching `JDBCConnectionException`. This is a subclass of `HibernateException` used for DB connection problems (including incorrect DB setup).

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/exception/JDBCConnectionException.html

Comment: The problem is at the at the main() level, it is actually a Spring BeanCreationException.  Furthermore, the root cause of the BeanCreationException is just a plain HibernateException.   This is why I'm trying to find out a better way of doing this.  I am unable to catch a JDBCConnectionException at this level.

Comment: What dooes getMostSpecificCause() method returns? This method is present in NestedRuntimeException (parent of BeanCreationException).

Comment: getMostSpecificCause() still shows a HibernateException:   `(org.hibernate.HibernateException) org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set`.  Even though I can see in a higher stack trace `2015-10-30 12:12:00,571 ERROR ConnectionPool - Unable to create initial connections of pool.
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'eric'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

Comment: @JackTheKnife no...  I don't believe I did and just left a generic error message.  Terrible solution but couldn't find a better way at the time